# dmsetup doesn't work with drives over 2TB

Tags: cryptsetup, truecrypt

The original title of this post was about CryptSetup not loading a Truecrypt device with 4096 byte sectors. I managed to dump the Truecrypt header (with the master key) anyway, but now when I try to load it with dmsetup it doesn't work:

```
echo "0 5860533168 crypt aes-xts-plain64 <my-super-secret-64-byte-key> 256 /dev/sdh 256" | dmsetup create test
device-mapper: resume ioctl on test  failed: Invalid argument
Command failed
```

It doesn't seem to support size numbers over 2^32 so I tried adding the **sector_size:4096** argument to the table:

```
echo "0 732566646 crypt aes-xts-plain64 <my-super-secret-64-byte-key> 256 /dev/sdh 256 sector_size:4096" | dmsetup create test
device-mapper: reload ioctl on test  failed: Invalid argument
Command failed
```

It works if I set the number of sectors to be **under 2TB** (2^32 * 512), but not over. I've tried to replicate the same command in pure cryptsetup, but I don't know how to match the dmsetup table exactly and I can't replicate it. Is there a way to force dmsetup to work with devices over 2TB? Is there a way to pass the master key directly to cryptsetup? This is what I've tried so far, but it decrypts with wrong key:

```
echo <64-byte-key> | cryptsetup open --type plain /dev/sdh test --offset 256 --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --hash plain --key-size 512
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total number of sectors was wrong. I had to take the total number of sectors and subtract the offset. Why didn't dmsetup just say that the number of sectors exceeded the device instead of the very unhelpful: "Invalid argument"? It would have saved hours.

For 4k mode, you have to take the total number of sectors * 512 / 4096 - offset. You also have to specify a **count** before any extra "optional paramaters" in the table. Here I only had 1 so it's:

```
... /dev/sdh 256 1 sector_size:4096
```